Expo Updates Custom Server Setup - Legacy manifests are no longer supported
I am trying to set a custom server for my expo OTA updates.

I have setup the expo project correctly and it works with expo default updates server.
I have a server let's say https://notes.aliaref.dev which can serve static files.

Steps to set the custom server

I change the app.json updates.url to my custom server url. which
looks like this
// other configs
"updates": {   
    "url": "https://notes.aliaref.dev",
    "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0,  
    "enabled": true
}


I tried npx expo export it created a dist directory and I copied all the contents of dist folder to my server. but when I launch the app
(release apk) it shows the error Error: Failed to parse manifest data: Legacy manifests are no longer supported

I also tried using eas command as eas update --branch apk --message "my message"

the channel name "apk" is correct I can update using this command with expo default servers.
This command also creates a dist directory inside my project as npx expo export
I copied all the files of this command also to my custom server and get the same error of Error: Failed to parse manifest data: Legacy manifests are no longer supported



I am testing on apk release and checking the logs using adb logcat
What I am missing ? I couldn't find any useful resources online.
